# Fading out the page while a youtube video is playing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, youtube, youtube-api

How can you fade out /or place a black semi-transparent cover over the entire page when an embedded youtube video is playing and have it go back to normal when the video is over or paused?

javascript?
jquery?

This is as far as I got, I don't know enough coding (just html/css) to use it though:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Adding_event_listener

I figured out how to use the API to call the video and have some event listener code I found in the API to call functions on state changes (ex play and end video), though I'm not sure why the listener part isn't working.. I don't have any experience with API's or javascript at this level..

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
swfobject.embedSWF(
    "http://www.youtube.com/v/TEHWDA_6e3M?enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer&version=3",
    "ytapiplayer", 
    "960", 
    "540", 
    "8", 
    null, 
    null, 
    params, 
    atts
);

function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
  ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
  ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
}

function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
   alert("Player's new state: " + newState);
}

});
```

Comment: overlay is the better option, since you can't apply opacity to an iframe (security reasons)

Comment: I don't want to overlay or change opacity for the video, just everything around it.. the rest of the page.

Comment: Are you using and JavaScript Youtube API? if so, can you provide the current setup for invoking the API so I can guide it from there.

Comment: Adding code to the question @Ohgodwhy

Comment: Ohhh...you're using just an iFrame, I'm not sure if it's possible using just the iFrame, and not actually including the YT API

Comment: How do I use the API? No idea..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a div with `position:fixed` and `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)` that covers the entire page and then place the video on top of it by listening for the onStateChanged event from the player. You will have to use the javascript player api for this to work.

Comment: Thanks! How do I "listen for the onStateChanged event from the player"?

Comment: Check out the following page https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Examples. Its has examples on how to embed a player and listen for player events

Comment: I edited my code above to show how far I got, I'm not really sure why I'm not getting an alert like the examples show I should.. I don't have experience with this level of Javascript or API's at all.